# How to merge two contents version with Quill.js?

Tags: quill

I am synchronizing the content of the textarea with a server and I'd like to merge both in case of conflict to keep the differences without showing twice things that didn't changed.

Does anyone have a strategy of how we could do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a trivial task. The two main approaches to do this is [Operational Transform](https://operational-transformation.github.io/) and [Conflict Free Replicated Data Types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conflict-free_replicated_data_type). A couple libraries that do this is [ShareJS](https://github.com/josephg/ShareJS) and [yjs](https://github.com/y-js/yjs).